# How to use Object.defineProperties()?

Tags: javascript

Below I am trying to define properties of an object using defineProperties function, but I am getting unexpected outcome when I print last line in this script. I expect 2005 to be logged at console, but I keep getting 2004. Same applies to other properties, like edition. Am I using this defineProperties 
 function incorrectly?

```js
var book = {};
Object.defineProperties(book, {
  _year: {
    value: 2004
  },
  edition: {
    value: 1
  },
  year: {
    get: function() {
      return this._year;
    },
    set: function(newValue) {
      if (newValue > 2004) {
        this._year = newValue;
        this.edition += newValue - 2004;
      }
    }
  }
});


console.log(book);
console.log(book.year);

book.year = 2005;

console.log(book);
console.log(book.year);
```

Comment: The default value for the `writable` flag is `false`. You have to explicitly set it to `true`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `_year` as read only, so `this._year = newValue` fails (silently). You need to make it writable.

```
  _year: {
    value: 2004,
    writable: true
  },
```

Comment: Dang, missed that. Thank you guys.